# Using babel, how can I append some code to the top of every file?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, transpiler

My goal is to fake out getting some requirejs code working via babel. I've found that if I add the following: `if (typeof define !== "function") { var define = require("amdefine")(module); }` to the top of every file while running in nodejs things seem to work out.

Here is some code I wrote, which I thought would work or nearly work:

```
function injectDefine(babel) {
    var header = 'if (typeof define !== "function") { var define = require("amdefine")(module); }';

    return new babel.Plugin('amdefine', {
        visitor: {
            Program: {
                enter: function(path, file) {
                    path.unshiftContainer(
                        'body',
                        babel.types.expressionStatement(
                            babel.types.stringLiteral(header)
                        )
                    );
                },
            },
        },
    });
}

require('babel-core/register')({
    stage: 0,
    plugins: [{transformer: injectDefine}],
});

require('../components/button');
```

The `components/button` file is just me trying to test that some file can load.

Other notes: I'm using babel 5, and I can't upgrade right now. I also can't use a `.babelrc` very easily right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tip 1: the environment variable `BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1` is needed if you are doing heavy testing of plugins. If you had a script that you ran like `npm run unit` you may instead want to run like `BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 npm run unit` while testing your plugin.

Tip 2: `babel.parse` will give you a full program out of some source. The easiest thing you could do is `babel.parse(header).program.body[0]`.

The following ended up working:

```
function injectDefine(babel) {

    var header = 'if (typeof define !== "function") { var define = require("amdefine")(module); }';

    return new babel.Plugin('amdefine', {
        visitor: {
            Program: {
                enter: function(node, parent) {
                    node.body.unshift(
                        babel.parse(header).program.body[0]
                    );
                },
            },
        },
    });
}

require('babel-core/register')({
    cache: false,
    stage: 0,
    plugins: [injectDefine],
});
```

Comment: Very nice - are you going to wrap this up as a nice babel-plugin-inject-banner ??  - I'm happy to push it and @ credit ;)

Comment: @ShortCircuit ahh good idea. Feel free to push and credit! I'd love to be added as an co-owner/author (npm user name: parris).

Comment: AFAIK, now in Babel 7 all modifications should be done via `NodePath` API, as @quirimmo's answer demonstrates

Answer (score 4):

At this stage, a cleaner solution can be to use `@babel/traverse` and `@babel/types`.

Let's suppose you want to append a comment to the top of every file, you could use some code like the following:

```js
// Import the required modules
import * as t from "@babel/types";
import traverse from "@babel/traverse";

// Get your ast (for this, you can use @babel/parser)

// Traverse your ast
traverse(ast, {
  // When the current node is the Program node (so the main node)
  Program(path) {
    // Insert at the beginning a string "Hello World" --> not valid JS code
    path.unshiftContainer('body', t.stringLiteral("Hello World"));
  }
});
```

Comment: Where do you place this code in regards to your `npm scripts`  defined in the `package.json` file? I also did not understand why you needed `t.stringLiteral`